# How can i give different url to my post

Tags: wordpress

I am creating a wordpress site Local.mensusa.com .

In this site I created so many post But all post showing same title (User Name) in title bar.
I need to change this with my post title .

Means each post should carry different articles.

Answer (score 0):

Go to WordPress `Dashboard`. Select `Settings` menu. In that select `Permalinks`. In the page select he option `Post name`. Your problem will be solved. I am suggesting this answer in the sense that you already have created the `.htaccess` file in the WordPress root directory. If not then copy the code below appearing in the permalink page when you select your option in the `Permalink`. Paste the code into a file named `.htaccess`(you should create it) in the WordPress root directory.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress dashboard > Settings > Permalinks > "Post Name" > Save Changes

*Note: The above will only work if you have a .htaccess file that is writeable by the server.*

If you're not happy with the URL you can go into the post in question and edit the permalink, this can be done under the title in the "Edit" post section.